# Контекст function и стрелочной функции

Tags: javascript, наследование, контекст

В чем отличие контекста function и стрелочной функции?
Почему, если изменить метод `logInfo` таким образом, то ничего не получим?

```js
logInfo: () => {
    console.log(`Name is ${this.name}`);
}
```

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello', this);
}

const person = {
  name: 'Misha',
  age: 20,
  sayHello: hello.bind(document),
  logInfo: function() {
    console.log(`Name is ${this.name}`);
  }
};

person.logInfo();
```

Comment: Не поверите, но this в стрелочных функциях не передаётся. Вернее ссылается на window.

Comment: @Quazimorda, Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context.

Comment: @NeedHate, всё верно, но как это противоречит тому, что this для стрелочной функции, ссылается на window?

Comment: @Quazimorda всегда ссылается на window?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ну, не всегда, конечно, но в данном конкретном случае - да. ))